# ASP.NET MVC load view into jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, url, dialog

I have a view that i access through the following URL:

domain.com/Records/Details/xxxx

where xxxx is the user ID e.g. 1234

In another view i have the users listed and on mouse hover i need to display their records in jQuery dialog.

Therefore i want to load the earlier mentioned view via URL into jquery dialog but somehow it does not work. Maybe i am doing something wrong?

```
open: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).load("/Records/Details/" + $(this).data("uid"));
}
```

data("uid") returns the correct value so i guess the issue is somewhere else.

Any ideas? Thank you